# How to call shell commands by using absolute path with spaces inside?

Tags: windows, console

This question is related to: [Why does calling drush command by system() fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628831/why-calling-drush-command-by-system-fails)

I need to launch a command like:

`C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe list site 1>NUL 2>NUL` but because of space this command fails.

I tried %20 in place of spaces, but with no luck.

Anyway I solved this issue by:

Replacing the

> C:\Users[Administrator]\Documents\IIExpress

with

> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

system("\"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe\" list site 1>NUL 2>NUL");

You need to put the command into quotes itself

Comment: Thanks this work: system('"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" list site 1>NUL 2>NUL', $retval), however I am getting error code 3

Comment: ah never mind looks like PHP  ... okay so appcmd is probably not launching correctly (why are you putting 1>NUL) ? are you not trying to capture the site list? the error code 3 is ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND see winerror.h for details so something is off about your path.

Comment: I am using 1>NUL to omit output of the command. Anyway without silencer error code is the same